# How to get mongodump --quiet to still report errors?

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to run `mongodump` so that it only outputs errors (to avoid extraneous logwatch reporting for an automated nightly backup script).

I've tried `mongodump --quiet` but from a quick test this supressess error messages also (running it at root folder without permission suppresses the "error creating directory" message that I get without `--quiet`).

How do I get only error output from `mongodump`?

Here's the error I get when running without `--quiet` but which I do NOT get with `--quiet`:

> 2016-04-17T13:50:26.294-0400  Failed: error dumping metadata: error creating directory for metadata file dump/234-watchdog: mkdir dump: permission denied

MongoDB is running on Ubuntu. I understand why this error is happening. I want errors like this NOT to be suppressed with the `--quiet` option.

Comment: How about piping the output to `grep`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
output="$(mongodump 2>&1)" || echo -e "$output"
```

This save both `stdout` and `stderr` into `output` variable, then if the command exit with not 0 exit code, echo the saved output.

Answer (score 1):

As you already said

> I've tried
>
> ```
> mongodump --quiet
> ```

As per mongodb documentation [Here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)

> Runs the mongodump in a quiet mode that attempts to limit the amount
>   of output.

**This option suppresses:**

```
output from database commands
replication activity
connection accepted events
connection closed events
```

`mongodump` is an useful tool to backup Mongo database. Apart from taking a cold backup, it can also take hot backup. i.e You can connect to a running instance of MongoDB and take a backup even when users are using the database.
There are two way you can mongdodump

1. Backup by Shutting down Mongod Instance
2. Backup without Shutting down Mongod Instance

For further your ref from `@RAMESH NATARAJAN` Blog [How to Backup and Restore MongoDB using mongodump and mongorestore](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/09/mongodump-mongorestore/)